# How to access a uitablviews selected item from the appdelegate?

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiapplicationdelegate

If I have a uitableview within a uitableview (yes the cells of the toplevel tableview are tableviews, but never mind that) on a tabbar tab and the user selects a row how can I get access to the selected item from my appdelegate and from the tabbar tabs

Mainly the question I have is if you have a var somewhere deep in your view heirachry how can a tabbar viewcontroller or the appdelegate get hold of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually use specific class to hold such variables. The source looks something like this:

```
static UIView *__someView = nil;
@implementation VariableContainer
+ (void)setSomeView:(UIView *)someView {
    __someView = someView;
}
+ (UIView *)someView {
    return __someView;
}    
@end
```

When you create some object you want to access from some distant object you just call [VariableContainer setSomeView:] and when you need to access it [VariableContainer someView].

This is just one of many ways you can achieve this same result. A few tips about this one:

- for every custom object (such as your app delegate) put in header "@class objectName"
- try importing this container only into source files (no headers)
- do not use retain, only have weak links
- you can put as many objects as you wish so have only 1 container

I hope this helps a bit.

Comment: I get the top half of this, but the bullet list not so much. Can ou give an example of the bullets implemented? The final bullet says more than one object, but someview a uiview var not an array

Comment: If you need an array use na array. What I meant was to put static UIView *__someView; static ApplicationViewController *__mainViewController;... Anything you need. And create setters and getters for each.
For the retain part you probably don't really need to retain those objects. If you do you have to release them explicitly (you will forget)
Do not import container into header files. In practice it can generate nasty errors when not using only links.
For passing links of custom objects like "AppNameViewController" you would need to import its header. Rather write @class AppNameViewController